# Why isn't my pdf opening?

Tags: texniccenter

I'm using TeXnicCenter and it generates pdfs fine but doesn't open them. Adobe pdf reader opens up but not the pdf. TeXnicCenter fails a command and this appears:

[image]

What's happening and how do I fix it?

---

UPDATE:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

[image]

Comment: Note that acroread is a poor choice of PDF viewer on Windows. (Terrible on GNU/Linux. Maybe OK on OS X - no idea.) You will need to close the PDF or open a new copy each time you compile. A viewer which updates the view when the PDF changes on disc is much easier to work with.

Comment: I've fixed it. I used acroviewR17 as the server.